# Laravel error page when creating CRUD application

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-5

Following code in `create.blade.php` in the `view->tasks->create.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

<h1>Add a New Task</h1>
<p class="lead">Add to your task list below.</p>
<hr>
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'tasks.store']) !!}

<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('title', 'Title:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
{!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('description', 'Description:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
{!! Form::textarea('description', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

{!! Form::submit('Create New Task', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
@stop
```

A task controller I created for the controller sections

```
Controller->TasksController 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class TasksController extends Controller {

public function index() {
    return view('tasks.index');
}
public function create() {
    return view('tasks.create');
}

}
```

inside our `config/app.php` We add one service provider

```
'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
```

aliases something like this

```
'Form'      => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
'Html'      => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
```

In a Vender->laravel->framework->src->Illuminate->Html->HtmlServiceProvider.php

Change the method name to bindingshare to the singleton.

IN The Route file Following code written.

```
Route::resource('tasks', 'TasksController');
```

Following Snapshot error display.

[image: Laravel error]

Comment: You can change `APP_DEBUG` to true in your `.env` for a proper error message

Comment: thanks.. for the suggestion. Now following error display:-

Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Task' not found

Comment: I am add this code in taskcontroller :-

 public function store(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required'
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();

        Task::create($input);

        Session::flash('flash_message', 'Task successfully added!');

        return redirect()->back();
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model `Task` is in other namespace, so you should after:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

add something like this:

```
use App\Models\Task;
```

or

```
use Task;
```

to use `Task` from valid namespace